# How can i call a javascript function

Tags: javascript

```
function () {
    function msg() {
        alert('hi there');    
    }

    function bla() {
        alert('hi there');    
    }
}
```

how can i call `msg()` or `bla()` function. I tried many way.

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Call them from where?  Inside of the outer (unnamed) function's body, they can be called by name, from outside that function they are not visible.

Comment: i want to call them from outer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define **inner** functions, the inner functions **will be accessible only from inside the outer function**! You cannot call them from outside the outer function declaring them like this!

If you want to **access them from outsid**e, you should declare them like this

```
function outer() { 
   this.msg = function() {
       alert("hi");
   }

   this.bla = function(){
       alert("hi again");
   }

}
```

And call them like this from your **HTML code**

`... onclick="(new outer()).bla();" value="ACTION"> ​`

Or call it from your **JavaScript Code** like this

```
    new outer().bla();
```

Comment: thanks this is what i need. but what if my outer function in a require?

Comment: I really don't know how to answer this.. :/ 
Please if my answer given was helpful to you give an upvote and set it as the solution for your question! thanks :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cyuwLzkf/122/ please check this. if i remove require area this is working.

Comment: give me 5 minutes! :)

Comment: This should be helpful: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare functions:

```
function msg() {
    alert('hi there');    
}

function bla() {
    alert('hi there');    
}
```

Call msg:

```
msg()
```

Call bla:

```
bla()
```